# Why is the syntax for taking the input about name not working?

Tags: c++, string, class, oop

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class data{
            string name;
            string code;
        public :
            void getname()
            {
                cout<<"Enter name : ";
                getline(cin,name);
            }
            void getcode()
            {
                cout<<"Enter code : ";
                getline(cin,code);
            }
            void display()
            {
                cout<<"Name : "<<name;
                cout<<"Code : "<<code;
            }
            };
int main()
{
    int n,i=0; cin>>n;
    data stud[n];
    while(i<n)
    {
        stud[i].getname();
        stud[i].getcode();
        i++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        stud[i].display();
    return 0;
}
```

In Line 13: The getline() is not executed. Can anyone explain its cause and an alternative?
Initially, I thought that I may have missed a header file or the syntax is wrong, but that is not the case as the syntax for input of *code* works just fine.

Comment: You have `getline(cin,code);` twice in your program. Nothing sets `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `cin` and `getline` function alternatively, you should clear the cin input stream. by using `cin.ignore()` funtion.
Here I am using `cin.ignore()` after your `cin` statements because you want to ignore the `"\n"` left in the buffer after taking your int variable with cin.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class data{
            string name;
            string code;
        public :
            void getname()
            {
                cout<<"Enter name : ";
                getline(cin,name);
            }
            void getcode()
            {
                cout<<"Enter code : ";
                getline(cin,code);
            }
            void display()
            {
                cout<<"Name : "<<name;
                cout<<"Code : "<<code;
            }
            };
int main()
{
    int n,i=0; 
    cin>>n;
    cin.ignore();
    data stud[n];
    while(i<n)
    {
        stud[i].getname();
        stud[i].getcode();
        i++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        stud[i].display();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope This Might Helps: )

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is a typo in this function

```
        void getname()
        {
            cout<<"Enter name : ";
            getline(cin,code);
                        ^^^^
        }
```

And this declaration of the array

```
int n,i=0; cin>>n;
data stud[n];
```

is invalid. The variable n is not initialized and variable length arrays is not a standard C++ geature.